# UIBarButtonType as a UIButton. Not on a NavigationBar!

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I would like to use the better styled UIBarButtonType as a typical UIButton. This is just to use on a view not a navigationBar.

I don't really want to recreate the button in an image app and apply to the various states. I know how to do it the other way around so there must be a way.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it works :

```
UIButton *info = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
UIBarButtonItem *infoBis = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:info];
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:infoBis, nil];
[tool setItems:array animated:YES]; //tool = UIToolbar
```

don't forget to put a target on your UIBarButtonItem ;)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that.
UIBarButtonItems are made just for UIToolbar and UINavigationBar. 
You need to create your own background image. It isn't a big issue, just few lines.

Comment: MacTeo, thanks mate. I ended up creating a subclass of the UIToolBar and drawing transparent pixels :

`code`- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"transparent.png"];  
 
    [image drawInRect:rect];
 [image release];
}
`code`
Then Adding the UIBarButtonItem of what I wanted to the instance of that Sub classed ToolBar. Then placing that where I needed. Worked fine. But I ended going a different route with the UI design so no one will see that implementation.